# React Hooks: How could I fill a modal component after a button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, modal-dialog, react-hooks

I coded a modal component: `Modal` that has this props:

```
interface IProps {
    isShowing: boolean,
    hide(): void,
    category: ICategory
}
```

This **modal is a form** that contains only one input:

```
const [name, setName] = useState(props.category.name)

// Other bunch of code.

const editCategory = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        
        e.preventDefault()
        const editedCategory: ICategory = {
            id: props.category.id,
            name
        }
        // Dispatch Action...
        props.hide()
    }


<label>Category Name</label>
<input value={name} onChange={e => { setName(e.target.value) }} />

<button onClick={editCategory}>Edit Category</button>
<button onClick={props.hide}>Cancel</button>
```

The **Parent component** has

```
const {isShowing, toggle} = useEditModal()
const [category, setCategory] = useState<ICategory>({id: 0, name: ""})

const updateCategory = (item: ICategory) => {
        setCategory(item)
        toggle()
    }

// foreach to create the table and so on... 
<th> <button onClick={ () => { updateCategory(item) }}>Update category</button> </th>
// More code...
<ModalEditCategory isShowing={isShowing} hide={toggle} category={category} />
```

So everything runs as expected except that the form is not displaying the current state of the selected category. So:

```
const updateCategory = (item: ICategory) => {
        setCategory(item)
        toggle()
    }
```

The set category happens after i toggle the modal. I know that this is the correct and asynchronous way of setState hooks in React but, Is there a way to fill the form after i update the state?

I know that there is a hook called useeffect, but the i entered on a infinite loop trying to show the modal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect is the best way to do this. However the "toggle" function would be a different object on every render, causing the useEffect to be triggered.

To prevent this, wrap the function "toggle" with a "useCallback" hook and then use it.

```
const toggleMemoized= useCallback(() => {
    toggle();
  }, []);
```

Comment: That prevent the infinite loop inside the useffect hook. But still the data does not appear inside the ModalForm.

`
useEffect(()=> {
// Prevent to toogle the first render.
        if (category.id !== 0 && !isShowing) {
            console.log(category)
            toggleMemoized()
        }
        
    }, [category])
`

Comment: can you put a console log inside useEffect to see if category ID is getting updated properly. 
If you have react-developer tools installed -> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Check if the state is being updated.